# Anychart fromJson Errors when setting Line Marker after Chart Draw

Tags: charts, line, marker, anychart, fromjson

I have been looking for a long time why I get error messages when I use the chart lineMarkers. 
I get a lot of NaN Errors when I hover the mouse over the series point.

Today I found out that it has to do with calling the chart.draw() function before setting the lineMarkers when reading the chart via Json.
But if I build the chart via api calls, this order doesn't matter and I get no errors.

Here I have built a small comparison:
https://playground.anychart.com/IuY9QbAl/2

I now know how to avoid this situation, but I would still like to know if this is a bug.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: I've just seen I used cartesian insted of scatter in the api call example.
Here's the updated version: https://playground.anychart.com/IuY9QbAl/4

now the order does matter! The errors now also occur in the non json chart.

Comment: Thank you for the report! We will investigate the issue and update you as soon as we get results.

Answer (score 0):

We are glad to notify you that AnyChart 8.9.0 has just released and it includes a fix for the issue you reported.

Now creating a Line Marker after `chart.draw()` call doesn't lead to JS exceptions and errors. The chart works as expected.

You can download the latest version from the download page - https://www.anychart.com/download/products/
Or update your links to the binaries on our CDN - https://cdn.anychart.com/